# Ternary operator in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
var result = from payroll in currentMonthPayroll
    select new SalaryDifference
    {
        PreviousMonthSalary = previousMonthPayroll.Where(t => t.EmployeeId == payroll.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault() == null ?
        default(decimal) : previousMonthPayroll.Where(t => t.EmployeeId == payroll.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault().Salary,
    };
```

Is there a way not to repeat the `previousMonthPayroll.Where(t => t.EmployeeId == payroll.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault()` logic to pick `Salary` value?

I tried:

```
previousMonthPayroll.Where(t => t.EmployeeId == payroll.EmployeeId)
    .FirstOrDefault().Salary ?? default(decimal);
```

But, if `previousMonthPayroll.Where(t => t.EmployeeId == payroll.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault()` is null, it throws exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As witnessed by all of the answers, there are several ways of doing this, my preferred way would be:

```
var result = from payroll in currentMonthPayroll
             select new SalaryDifference
             {
                 PreviousMonthSalary = previousMonthPayroll
                     .Where(t => t.EmployeeId == payroll.EmployeeId)
                     .Select(prev => prev.Salary)
                     .FirstOrDefault()
             };
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx)

```
previousMonthPayroll.Where(t => t.EmployeeId == payroll.EmployeeId)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(yourDefaultObject)
                    .First();
```

Where `yourDefaultObject` is an object with the default salary of `default(decimal)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `let` keyword:

```
from payroll in currentMonthPayroll
let prevSalary = previousMonthPayroll.FirstOrDefault(t => t.EmployeeId == payroll.EmployeeId)
select new SalaryDifference
{
    PreviousMonthSalary = prevSalary != null ? prevSalary.Salary : default(decimal)
};
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C# 6.0, you could mix the safe nav operator with the null coalescing operator:

```
PreviousMonthSalary = previousMonthPayroll
                     .Where(t => t.EmployeeId == payroll.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault()?.Salary 
                     ?? default(decimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing, in effect, is joining across enumerable sequences, so why not say so and let LINQ take care of the details:

```
  var result = from currentPayroll in currentMonthPayroll
               join previousPayroll in previousMonthPayroll on currentPayroll.EmployeeId equals previousPayroll.EmployeeId
               into joined
               from r in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new SalaryDifference
               {
                 PreviousMonthSalary = r == null ? default(decimal) : r.Salary,
               };
```

This will also have the benefit of being much more efficient than the other approaches.