# Getting data from database and filtering it by nullable string in ASP.Net MVC and Entity Framwork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, filtering, query-string

I have `Computers` table in my database and it is sent to controller in view model (vm here).

I send some filter with query string and want to filter `Computers` table data with these filters which is NOT NULL.

For example:

- If producer is sent, filter by producer,
- If producer and memoryType is sent, filter by producer and memoryType.

Code:

```
//GET: Product/notebooks
[Route("Product/Notebooks")]
public ActionResult Notebooks(string producer, string os, string memoryType, string memory, string displayType, string processorType, string ram, string vc)
{
    ViewBag.Producer = producer;
    ViewBag.OS = os;
    ViewBag.MemoryType = memoryType;
    ViewBag.Memory = memory;
    ViewBag.DisplayType = displayType;
    ViewBag.ProcessorType = processorType;
    ViewBag.RAM = ram;
    ViewBag.VC = vc;

    var vm = Methods.Methodss.createHIVM();
    return View(vm);
}
```

`createHIVM();` method here and working everywhere:

```
public static HomeIndexVM createHIVM()
{
    ProtelEntities dbProtel = new ProtelEntities();

    var phones = dbProtel.Phones.ToList();
    var producers = dbProtel.Producers.ToList();
    var computers = dbProtel.Computers.ToList();
    var sliders = dbProtel.Sliders.ToList();
    var contact = dbProtel.Contacts.FirstOrDefault();
    var memoryTypes = dbProtel.MemoryTypes.ToList();
    var memories = dbProtel.Memories.ToList();
    var rams = dbProtel.RAM.ToList();
    var cameras = dbProtel.Cameras.ToList();
    var displaytypes = dbProtel.DisplayTypes.ToList();
    var OS = dbProtel.OS.ToList();
    var osversions = dbProtel.OSVersions.ToList();
    var proCategories = dbProtel.ProCategory.ToList();
    var processorTypes = dbProtel.ProcessorTypes.ToList();
    var simTypes = dbProtel.SimTypes.ToList();
    var vcCategories = dbProtel.VCCategories.ToList();
    var vcSubcategories = dbProtel.VCSubcategories.ToList();
    var vcMemories = dbProtel.VCMemories.ToList();

    var vm = new HomeIndexVM
        {
            Computers = computers,
            Phones = phones,
            Producers = producers,
            Sliders = sliders,
            Contact = contact,
            Cameras = cameras,
            VCSubcategories = vcSubcategories,
            VCMemories = vcMemories,
            VCCategories = vcCategories,
            SimTypes = simTypes,
            DisplayTypes = displaytypes,
            Memories = memories,
            MemoryTypes = memoryTypes,
            OS = OS,
            OSVersions = osversions,
            ProCategories = proCategories,
            ProcessorTypes = processorTypes,
            RAMs = rams
        };

    return vm;
}
```

Comment: Basic Linq filtering can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations  If you've tried something and it isn't working as expected, update your question to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: how can I add if condition here?

`
var computers = from com in dbProtel.Computers
                            where com.Producers.ProducerName == producer 
                            select com;
`

Comment: You should take some look at [Ternary Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). And for examples have a look at [Using Ternary operators with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559242/ternary-operator-in-linq)

Comment: @Eminİsrafilzadə you can add condition like this `dbContext.Where(g=>stringIsNullOrEmpty(value) || g.Producer==producer)`

Comment: @Eldho how can I add more than one condition to check one by one?
producer, RAM, memoryType and etc...

Comment: As you have separate query you can do one by one. But  i think the above code will be bottleneck when you going forward.  var phones = dbProtel.Phones.ToList(); considering this if you have 500 items in phone db your giving more data to customer than you want

Comment: @Eldho seperate query returns me just nothing. In this case I have tu apply many many if conditionals. I don't know how to deal with it

Comment: I suggest to start with with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations

Answer (score 0):

> In this case I have tu apply many many if conditionals. I don't know how to deal with it

As the old saying goes. "How do you eat an elephant?  The same as everything else, one bite at a time."

You've got a big method with conditions that apply to several lookups. Some conditions will apply to several. So break it up. You won't be doing yourself any favors with class and method names like "Methods" and "Methods.Methodss"

```
public class EquipmentLookupService
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context = null;

    public EquipmentLookupService(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }

    public IEnumerable<Computer> GetComputers(string manufacturer, string processor)
    {
        var query = _context.Computers.AsQueryable();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(manufacturer))
            query = query.Where(x => x.Manufacturer == manufacturer);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(processor))
            query = query.Where(x => x.Processor == processor);

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then your controller action changes more to something like:

```
var vm = new HomeIndexVM
{
    Computers = EquipmentLookupService.GetComputers(manufacturer, processor),
    Phones = EquipmentLookupService.GetPhones(manufacturer),
    // etc...
};
return View(vm);
```

As a very basic starting example. You can create methods to load each type of lookup and add whatever conditions apply to each lookup.

Linq queries can contain conditional statements like:

```
query = _context.Computers.Where(x => (manufacturer == null || x.Manufacturer == manufacturer) && (processor == null || x.Processor == processor));
```

which might seem like less code, however I don't recommend using conditional code like this inside Linq expressions. Firstly, it can be much harder to read and can hide logic errors with misplaced parenthesis or operations. Secondly, it gets built down into SQL leading to larger, more complex SQL statements for conditions that simply don't need to be applied. In the previous example, the conditional check is kept in code, so criteria is only added to the generated SQL statements if they are needed.

The key to writing efficient (fast) Linq is to avoid prematurely executing an expression such as doing a `ToList()` before adding conditions. This ends up returning a lot of unnecessary data from the database to the server, requiring time and memory before the data is filtered.