# Null value in query using Select statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to create a query that will return an AgencyContractData object containing a DocumentDto object, but it may be that the original object does not contain a foreign key on the Document. I can't use ternary operator in an Entity-Framwork LINQ query. How it is possible to implement it (Required that select be converted to sql query)?

```
var contractList = await query
                .Select(contract => new AgencyContractData
                {
                    ContractId = contract.Id,
                    ContractNumber = contract.ContractNumber,
                    CustomerId = contract.CustomerId,
                    CustomerName = contract.CustomerName,
                    Group = contract.Group,
                    CommodityType = contract.CommodityType,
                    SupplierName = contract.SupplierName,
                    StartDate = contract.StartDate,
                    EndDate = contract.EndDate,
                    ExecutionDate = contract.ExecutionDate,
                    ContractUnit = contract.ContractUnit,
                    Comment = contract.Comment,
                    Pricing = contract.Pricing,
                    SecondaryCustomerName = contract.SecondaryCustomerName,
                    ContractType = contract.ContractType,
                    AnnualVolume = contract.AnnualVolume,
                    Document = new DocumentDto
                    {
                        DocumentId = contract.Document.Id,
                        CounterPartyId = contract.Document.CounterPartyId,
                        FilePath = contract.Document.FilePath,
                        DocumentTitle = contract.Document.DocumentTitle,
                        IsCustomerUpload = contract.Document.IsCustomerUpload,
                        DocumentBytes = null
                    },
                    DocumentName = contract.DocumentName,
                    ContractNumberInt = contract.ContractNumberInt,
                    ContractNumberString = contract.ContractNumberString,
                    MsaBaseNumber = contract.MsaBaseNumber,
                    NotificationDays = contract.NotificationInDays,
                    State = contract.State,
                    CreatedOn = contract.CreatedOn,
                    CreatedBy = contract.CreatedBy,
                    ModifiedOn = contract.ModifiedOn,
                    ModifiedBy = contract.ModifiedBy,
```

It is the AgencyContract entity:

```
    public class Contract : IEntity<long>
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string ContractNumber { get; set; }

        public long? ContractUnitId { get; set; }

        public int? NumPricePeriods { get; set; }

        public double? Tolerance { get; set; }

        public ContractTypeEnum? ContractType { get; set; }

        public ContractTolerancePeriodEnum? ContractTolerancePeriod { get; set; }

        public bool IsRelyContract { get; set; }

        public int TermsEndNoticeDays { get; set; }

        public bool IsProrated { get; set; }

        public bool IsContinuation { get; set; }

        public long SupplierId { get; set; }

        public long? DocumentId { get; set; }

        public long? BrokerId { get; set; }

        public BillTypeEnum? BillType { get; set; }

        public string ExternalId { get; set; }

        #region Navigation Properties

        public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

        public virtual Broker Broker { get; set; }

        public virtual ContractUnit ContractUnit { get; set; }

        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

        public virtual List<UsnAccountToContract> UsnAccountToContracts { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ProviderLookup> ProviderLookups { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ContractNotification> ContractNotifications { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ContractVolume> ContractVolumes { get; set; }

        public virtual Document Document { get; set; }

        #endregion
```

And I want to make a AgencyContractData object using Select:

```
public class AgencyContractData
    {
        public int? AnnualVolume { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public AgencyCommodityTypeEnum CommodityType { get; set; }

        public long ContractId { get; set; }

        public string ContractNumber { get; set; }

        public long? ContractNumberInt { get; set; }

        public string ContractNumberString { get; set; }

        public int? ContractReportLevelByGlobalSearch { get; set; }

        public AgencyContractTypeEnum ContractType { get; set; }

        public AgencyContractUnitEnum ContractUnit { get; set; }

        public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public long? CustomerId { get; set; }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public string DocumentName { get; set; }

        public DocumentDto Document { get; set; }

        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime ExecutionDate { get; set; }

        public string Group { get; set; }

        public List<AgencyLocationData> Locations { get; set; }

        public Guid? LockedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? LockedOn { get; set; }

        public string Md5Hash { get; set; }

        public Guid? ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

        public string MsaBaseNumber { get; set; }

        public int? NotificationDays { get; set; }

        public DateTime? NotificationSentOn { get; set; }

        public string Pricing { get; set; }

        public string SecondaryCustomerName { get; set; }

        public int Sites { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }

        public string SupplierName { get; set; }
```

Comment: "it may be that the original object does not contain a foreign key on the Document" then how do you propose to identify it? Please add your object model

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? The `Document` navigation property (using the foreign key) should work?

Comment: @Charlieface I need to create AgencyContractData object using Select that should be converted to sql. But if not associated Document navigation property with Contract is null, I have an exception that can not convert null to int64 (documentId). Sorry for my english(

Comment: Well if it's null what do you propose to happen? Maybe you want `Document = contract.Document == null ? null : new DocumentDto...`

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I want the logic to be like this. But ternary operator is not convertible to sql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559242/ternary-operator-in-linq

Comment: @marsze why? what if I don't need to take all of properties of entity? for example: my entity has 40 props, but I need only 5. This doesn't mean that I have to get all 40 from the database

Comment: @TerentiyGatsukov You would use a [projection](https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-projection) for that: `.Select(contract => new { contract.Id, contract.Document })`

Comment: Please add a tag for the ef version you're using.

Comment: Did you actually try `Document = contract.Document == null ? null : new DocumentDto...` as proposed by @Charlieface?  I don't see why it shouldn't work. Even EF6 (old) allows it.

Comment: Another option would be to use Automapper and its `ProjectTo` method as this will handle all optional relationships pretty much out of the box.  Otherwise post the code that you have tried such as the "can't use ternary operator".. Charlieface's example should work fine for conditionally adding the DocumentDto.